# Converting an extended react component class to work with typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am currently attempting to convert a project from react to typescript.

So I currently have a jsx file I want to convert to tsx and the code is the following

```
class Button extends React.Component {


    onClickCallback = e => {
        if(this.props.onClick){
            this.props.onClick(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I am wondering what the first steps would be, I need to create the props right?

```
props = {onClick: } // But what would it be? {}?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

glad you are adapting Typescript in your project :)

When using Typescript in React you would do something like below:

```
type ButtonProps = {
  // Function props is typed as (arg: ArgumentType) => ReturnType.
  // `event` is the argument type for the function.
  // `void` is the return type of the function.
  onClick?: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => void
}

// Class component.
class Button extends React.Component<ButtonProps> {
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.props.onClick} />
    )
  }
}

// Function component.
const Button: React.FC<ButtonProps> = ({ onClick }) => {
  return (
    <button onClick={onClick} />
  )
}
```

Hope this clarifies how to type React component with Typescript.

Comment: Yes it does thank you, I was so confused on how to incorporate the HTML values! Cheers

Comment: Glad it helped! I'm not sure about other editors but on VSCode, if you hover over the HTML element's prop, it will give you the expected type as well. So you could reference that type to help typing your props better :)